# How to write a Tableau query?

Tags: tableau-api

In my tableau Query, I want to filter data according to particular sales interval. So if a user selects a particular range the data corresponding to that range is only displayed. How can I do that?

I am attaching a image which will be used as a filter. And I am using global superstore data with category, sub category and sales in a bar graph format.

[image]

Comment: I don't think [your "urgent" requirement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) is very popular here...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate something like your image (values and IDs), without using "simple filters", you have to create calculated fields.

The first one (dimension), let's say Interval Sales, is something like:

```
IF[Sales] <= 100 then '<= 100'
  ELSEIF [Sales] <= 200 then '100-200'
  ELSEIF [Sales] <= 300 then '200-300'
  ELSEIF [Sales] <= 400 then '300-400'
  ELSE '>= 400'
END
```

The other one (Sales Interval Id) it's similar but you have to "generate" IDs with the same logic.

Once you've these 2 calculated fields, just create a simple table in a new worksheet like this:

[image]

Assuming that you already have a worksheet with your Category-SubCategory chart, create a Dashboard containing both sheets and create a filter action in order to filter from your Filter-sheet:

[image]

The result should be something like this:
[image]

Comment: If the approach bore does not return the results you,want, you might need to learn about other features such as LOD calcs or bins

Comment: if the answer was useful, could you please accept it in order to "close" the post?